# Nginx: allow access only to referrer that match location name

Tags: nginx, http-referer

Is there a way, in nginx, to allow access to a "location" only to clients with a referrer that matches the current location name?

This is the scenario:

http://foooooo.com/bar.org/

http://foooooo.com/zeta.net/

etc etc

I want the contents of the bar.org location available only if the referrer is bar.org. The same goes for zeta.net

I know I can do this "statically", but there are a lot of those locations and I need to find a way to do this defining only one "dynamic" location.

Sorry for my bad english.

**SOLUTION**

I've solved this way:

```
location ~/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]*)/* {
    set $match "$1::$http_referer";
    if ($match !~* ^(.+)::http[s]*://[www]*[.]*\1.*$ ) {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any rule for the location, for example always the string in before the first slash(`/`). If yes, I have a solution.

Comment: Yes, locations are all in the same format.

Comment: OK, I got you. Have a look at my answer. Any question please feel free to comment here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
location ~ ^/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]*)/(.*) {
    if ($http_referer !~ "^$1.*$"){
            return 403;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, you give me the right way to go, I'll edit my answer to include the code I've used.

Answer (score 6):

```
location /india/xxxxx.js {
    if ($http_referer !~ "http://domain.xxx/"){
            return 403;
    }
}
```

I solved my problem using slight changes, Thanks

Comment: underrated answer

Comment: The only one actually does work correctly.