# How to serve two web applications behind an nginx reverse proxy

Tags: express, nginx, proxy

I have two web applications (node.js express apps), `web1` and `web2`.  These web apps expect to be hosted on sites that are typically something like `http://www.web1.com` and `http://www.web2.com`.  I'd like to host them behind an nginx reverse proxy as `https://www.example.com/web1` and `https://www.example.com/web2`.  I do not want to expose the two web apps as two subdomains on `example.com`.

Here is a snippet of my nginx configuration (without SSL termination details) that I had hoped would accomplish this:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name .example.com;

  location /web1 {
    proxy_pass http://www.web1.com:80;
  }

  location /web2 {
    proxy_pass http://www.web2.com:80;
  }
}
```

This works, except for the relative links that the web apps use.  So web app `web1` will have a relative link like `/js/script.js` which won't be handled correctly.

What is the best/standard way to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't know ngix, but in the web request there is the http referrer that is the the page "preceding" the current request. Can you map the referrer in ngix?

Comment: I seen some places that see this as a potential solution but I am unsure of how this might be implemented.

Comment: look this: http://serverfault.com/questions/177304/different-nginx-rules-based-on-referrer

Answer (score 4):

I think something like this:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name .example.com;
  location /web1 {
    proxy_pass http://www.web1.com:80;
  }
  location /web2 {
    proxy_pass http://www.web2.com:80;
  }
  location / {
    if ($http_referer ~* (/web1) ) {
        proxy_pass http://www.web1.com:80;
    }
    if ($http_referer ~* (/web2) ) {
        proxy_pass http://www.web2.com:80;
    }
  }
```

Comment: This looks pretty good.  Any chance you know the what the referer header should be set to in express?

Comment: Ifs should be avoided,
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do this by checking the `$http_referer`, something like:

```
location / {
  if ($http_referer ~ ^http://(www.)?example.com/web1) {
    proxy_pass http://www.web1.com:80;
  }

  if ($http_referer ~ ^http://(www.)?example.com/web2) {
    proxy_pass http://www.web2.com:80;
  }
}
```

The browser would be setting the referer to `http://example.com/web1/some/page` when it requests `/js/script.js` so the apps shouldn't need to change, unless they need to process or care about the referer internally.

The $http_referer does not seem to be easy to find in nginx docs, but is mentioned in a few sites:

- http://nginx.2469901.n2.nabble.com/HTTP-Referer-Module-td3356604.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18917016/1422492

Answer (score 1):

How about using cookie and `ngx_http_map_module`?

Add `add_header Set-Cookie "site=web1;Path=/;Domain=.example.com;";` to `location /web1 {...}` (web2 too).

Add `map` to under `http`

```
map $cookie_site $site {
  default http://www.web1.com:80;
  "web2" http://www.web2.com:80;
}
```

Default location is this

```
location / {
    proxy_pass $site;
}
```

You can pass the value of cookie to `proxy_pass` directly. But, using map is more secure way.