# allowed-list of referrer header in nextjs

Tags: next.js, referrer

How are you?

I have a question regarding the header referrer.
In a pentest analysis to my app in nextjs I was told that it is allowing to pass a different header referrer to the allowed ones. For which I must implement a white list that does not allow access to resources if the referrer header is different.

I leave an image of the observation

[Referrer header edited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avdi7.png)

Do you know how I could implement this validation from NextJs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ask that you front your app with a layer than implementing NextJS for referrer whitelisting, you could utilize a CDN or a Nginx proxy

- For CDN's, using something like Cloudflare's [referrer
  whitelisting](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/firewall-rule-to-block-referers-other-than-the-sites-domain/72115/12)
- Another option is to use nginx [referrer policies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18917016/13749957)

If these are not options, then you could build a custom nextjs server
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server and then look at the `req` object to make your responses conditional, i.e send to a 403 page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, we analyzed the alternatives and the option we had was to implement a Nextjs Custom Server, we added the validation of the allowed domains inside the custom server and compared it with the header referrer, we managed to solve it. Greetings!

Comment: Excellent, glad that it worked out @JoelFernandez